# comparing multiple IEnumerables for distinct and different records

Tags: c#, linq, active-directory, hashset

I am comparing the active directory groups of 3 or more users, and I will never know the number of users to compare before the program is run.  What I am ultimately trying to do is to get a list of similar active directory groups between the users I am comparing and a list of the non-similar groups for the users.  I also want to be able to tell what user is assigned to the non-similar groups which adds another issue in the comparison.  Here is the code I have so far.  Basically I foreach though this for every user but then I am stuck on not only how to compare them all, but how to store all of the IEnumerable objects before I have to compare them.

```
        using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain"))
        {
            using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName))
            {
                return user.GetGroups();
            }
        }
```

Since I don't know the number of users, I don't how many Ienumerables I need to create to store the groups, much less compare them all.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried using a hashset, but I couldn't figure out how to retain the users properties along with the group assignments when I did this.

Comment: Are you looking for the facsimile of [`IEnumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)?

Comment: this question needs to be expanded upon. it would be helpful for an example like that has a bit of sample input and expected output. i also feel like you have code outside of this that is going to change this question drastically, like perhaps a loop for lots of different users calling this code?

Comment: I looked at IEnumerable.Intersect, but I will be comparing more than 2 IEnumerables.

Comment: Intersection is associative, meaning that you can just recursively intersect groups with each other and the final result will be the intersection of all of them. So for three users, the groups they are all in is Intersect(Intersect(group1, group2), group3).

Comment: I'm looking into nesting the Intersects.  I'll let you know if I am successful.